# Specific case of dangling reference during destruction

Tags: c++

This is the code I cannot change and have to adapt to:

```
struct SomeInterface
{
   ...
};

struct SomeClass
{
   SomeClass(SomeInterface& iface) : iface(iface) {}
   SomeInterface& iface;
   ...
};
```

I have to write a function where I will get `SomeInterface` from other function and return pointer to `SomeClass` which takes a reference to `SomeInterface`. The problem was, unique_ptr to `SomeInterface` will be created on that function stack so reference is gonna be invalid after returning from it. I wrote a simple wrapper class which inherits from `SomeClass` and extends it to hold a unique_ptr to `SomeInterface`.

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> getSomeClass()
{
   struct SomeClassWrapper : public SomeClass
   {
      SomeClassWrapper(std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface> iface) 
        : SomeClass(*iface), 
          iface(std::move(iface)) {}

      std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface> iface;
   };

   std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface> iface = getIfaceFromSomewhere();

   return std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>(std::make_unique<SomeClassWrapper>(std::move(iface))
}
```

This solves `SomeInterface's` lifetime problem... almost. Unfortunately during destruction of `SomeClassWrapper` the member variable `iface` is destroyed first, so for a brief moment base class `SomeClass` holds a dangling reference.

How to achieve my desired result without this problem?

Cheers

Comment: If `SomeInterface` object is created on the stack, there is no way to protect against that! Looks like there is a lot of confusion here. Worst, we do not have all the necessary code to understand the problem. Please post [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant pointer to SomeInterface is created on stack, the object it refers to is created earlier I'm gonna try to draw some minimal working example up later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `unique_ptr` into a base class that is constructed first and destructed last:

```
struct SomeClassWrapperPtrMember {
    std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface> iface;
};

struct SomeClassWrapper : public SomeClassWrapperPtrMember, SomeClass
{
     SomeClassWrapper(std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface> iface) 
        : SomeClassWrapperPtrMember{std::move(iface)},
          SomeClass(*(this->iface)) {}
};
```

Comment: Notice the need of `this->` as argument `iface` has been moved.